# "availability: InStock" isn't shown in Google Rich Snippet

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I’m using Schema.org properties to provide product data of my webpage to search engines. Everything works great(stars, nr. of reviews and price are shown), but availability(In stock) isn't shown in the rich snippet results?
Anyone knows why my availability isn't working(isn't shown in rich snippet result)?

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Honey",
  "image": "https://www.myimage.webp",
  "description": "honey",
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Brand",
    "name": "My Brand"
  },
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "5.0",
    "reviewCount": "12"
  },
  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "url": "https://www.mysite.php",
    "priceCurrency": "EUR",
    "price": "10.00",
    "priceValidUntil": "2024-12-31",
    "itemCondition": "NewCondition",
    "availability": "InStock",
    "shippingDetails": {
      "@type": "OfferShippingDetails",
      "shippingRate": {
        "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
        "value": 10.00,
        "currency": "EUR"
      },
      "deliveryTime": {
        "@type": "ShippingDeliveryTime",
        "handlingTime": {
          "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
          "minValue": 0,
          "maxValue": 1,
          "unitCode": "DAY"
        },
        "transitTime": {
          "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
          "minValue": 1,
          "maxValue": 3,
          "unitCode": "DAY"
        }
      },
      "shippingDestination": {
        "@type": "DefinedRegion",
        "addressCountry": {
          "@type": "Country",
          "name": "HR"
        }
      }
    },
    "hasMerchantReturnPolicy": {
      "@type": "MerchantReturnPolicy",
      "refundType": "FullRefund",
      "returnPolicyCategory": "https://schema.org/MerchantReturnFiniteReturnWindow",
      "returnMethod": "https://schema.org/ReturnByMail",
      "returnFees": "https://schema.org/ReturnShippingFees",
      "merchantReturnDays": 5,
      "applicableCountry": {
        "@type": "Country",
        "name": "HR"
      },
      "returnShippingFeesAmount": {
        "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
        "value": 10.00,
        "currency": "EUR"
      }
    }
  },
  "review": [
    {
      "@type": "Review",
      "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "A"
      },
      "datePublished": "2023-04-11",
      "reviewRating": {
        "@type": "Rating",
        "ratingValue": "5"
      },
      "reviewBody": "Top!"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Review",
      "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "M"
      },
      "datePublished": "2023-02-08",
      "reviewRating": {
        "@type": "Rating",
        "ratingValue": "5"
      },
      "reviewBody": "Perfect!"
    },
    ...
```